# What are the PowerShell consoles for Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, powershell, console

Linux is known for having lots of terminals and consoles that are built upon GTK, Qt, GNOME, KDE or X to run the shell (like bash). PowerShell on Windows runs with the Windows console (the same as used for cmd.exe) by default.

What are the other consoles or terminals available for Windows that support PowerShell?

Answer (score 21):

Another [Console Emulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/), I developing.

> ConEmu-Maximus5 is a Windows console emulator with tabs, which
>   presents multiple consoles and simple GUI applications as one
>   customizable GUI window with various features.
>
> Today, ConEmu can be used with any other console application or simple
>   GUI tools (like PuTTY for example). ConEmu is an active project, open
>   to suggestions.

It is highly customizable terminal with long feature list. For example:

- Tabs, you can easily (re)run selected tab as Administrator or another account
- Windows 7 Jump Lists and Progress on Taskbar buttons
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 colors
- configurable and clickable status bar
- optional Quake/tilde style
- Change cursor position with mouse click (cmd, powershell, tcc/le, ...)
- (experimental) [PowerShell pane inside Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/a/441531/139371) window (build 120625)

Comment: Maximus: The PowerShell pane inside Explorer feature is an awesome addition to ConEmu! Thanks for implementing it!!! :-)

Comment: ConEmu is really the best, I've tried many and most had just basic improvements over what cmd.exe offers while ConEmu is a piece of incredible work and a lot of thought has been put into it. It feels like finally someone got it right. To get even more power install clink with ConEmu and you'll get best experience you can on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Have a loot at the [Console Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) over at SourceForge.

From their website:

> Console is a Windows console window enhancement. Console features
>   include: multiple tabs, text editor-like text selection, different
>   background types, alpha and color-key transparency, configurable font,
>   different window styles

Answer (score 4):

There does not seem to be a great selection, but I am new to PowerShell and I have not tried 'Poshconsole' but it looks interesting.

[image: Snip snip of part of 'poshconsole']

It is opensource working under the Microsoft Permissive License (Ms-PL).

[This links to the Home Page](http://poshconsole.codeplex.com/)

This links to Download page that has reviews of different versions and new release notes.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell ISE would be my pick.  It's a WPF application.