# How to embed PowerShell into Explorer or Explorer-like tool?

Tags: windows-explorer, powershell

I typically find myself using both Windows Explorer (for navigation and viewing) and PowerShell (for commands).

Is there any way to embed the PowerShell console into Windows Explorer? Or is there any Explorer-like tool that can embed a PowerShell console into one of its panes?

Note that I am not looking for a "Open PowerShell here" option that opens PowerShell in a different window. I want the PowerShell window to be embedded inside Explorer as a pane.

Comment: I don't know of any specifics if you are looking to have it integrated side by side style, but I do know you can quickly hit Alt+D, and type in "powershell get-command" etc to have something done, if need be.

Comment: Bearocalypse: I am aware of this shortcut. However, I am looking for a way to embed Powershell into the Explorer window itself.

Comment: There was an extension that would host a command prompt in an Explorer bar in Windows Explorer. It's kind of surprising no such thing exists for PowerShell. This is a good idea!

Comment: two questions ;) 1. can you accept my answer? 2. may be we'll retag question and add "conemu" tag?

Comment: Maximus: Done the accept. Cannot tag with question with conemu, because that is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?
[image]
I've just implemented this funny feature in [ConEmu 120625](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), so, may be buggy :) However, it works (test passed) in Windows 7 and Windows 8 RP.

Sample reg file - "ConEmu\Addons\ConEmu_Inside.reg".

Be sure, that preview/detail pane exists before calling "ConEmu Inside".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? Perhaps you can extend it or ask the author to?

http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar.html

Comment: Thanks! It can create a console window, but cannot embed it inside the Explorer window.

Comment: As a recommendation @Hob Gadling, it is generally preferable to not just copy in a link to someplace else as an answer to a question.  It is helpful to include a high level overview of your answer and what is included in the link at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I use the (free) PowerGUI Script Editor which is a far better editor than the built-in ISE, IMHO.

PowerGUI has some downloadable add-ons, one of which is a Script Explorer. I've not really used add-ons much. In this one you have to add in folders and files manually, which isn't great, but might be ok for what you want.

Answer (score -3):

Just launch the "Windows Powershell Integrated Scripting Environment" (ISE)" and you will be in business!

It is the graphic user interface of powershell with multiline editing, tab completion, syntax coloring, selective execution and context-sensitive help.

Note: If you are on a Windows Server 2008 box, you will have to add this feature via "Add Features"

Comment: Does the ISE have a Explorer or file manager inside it? I have not seen it.

Comment: The Downvote is because the "answer" has nothing to do with the question.