# Is it possible to have interactive directory tree view next to console

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

To anyone's knowledge, is it possible to accomplish something like the following screenshot:

[image: console mod]

Ideally, I'd like to double click on a file and process the file as if I typed it directly into the conole and double clicking on a directory would execute `cd <clicked directory>` in the console.  I use conemu right now, and there is a lot possible with that program and I discover new features every time I use it.

I'm not sure, but it seems like something of this nature may be implemented in Direct FTP by Coffee Cup Software ([Link to software description](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coffeecup.com%2Fdirect-ftp%2F&ei=j6qxU4riBrOI8QHu3oGQDw&usg=AFQjCNGrkRua7g47kbX8xnz4YtjVZ7xBDQ&sig2=MQdT9icFrILn3G3GaGoMJw&bvm=bv.69837884,d.b2U)), but that is designed to be remote, and I can't tell if it is interactive in the way I want.

Any insight?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/317261/139371

Comment: That's pretty close - and by the way (God Bless you for your creation).  But two things I haven't been able to do with it.  1.   I would like to show only the tree view (hiding the contents of the folder) - now I  can only get it to show up in the preview pane or below the tree and folder contents.  2.  It doesn't sync folder click to invoke `cd` to that directory.  It's pretty close, and I think I will use it more, but those two other features would be killer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [comment](https://superuser.com/q/317261/139371), ConEmu has `Inside` ability. And it can sync folder! Look at "Sync" column in the status bar (it may be disabled by default).

As for view representation of explorer window - that is the issue to your "browser". You may even create small wrapper around ConEmu if you know C#/Basic/C++...

At last, if you drag&drop some file from explorer pane to ConEmu - the name will be pasted.

[image: ConEmu inside]